# Could not find file [Visual Studio]

Tags: visual-studio

I have cpp and header files in my solution. I moved them from the default solution folder to a subfolder. Now visual studio says it can't find the files in the old place. How do I tell VS to search in a new folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on Solution Explorer window `View - Solution Explorer`. Hover over your files in the new directory, right click on them and choose `Include in project`. Hover over these same files in old directory and choose `Exclude from project`.